# how to convert string to int c#

Tags: c#, string, int, type-conversion

I want to convert a string (`w.main.temp`) to an integer. I'm using the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections;

namespace project1
{

    interface IWeatherDataService
{
       // public WeatherData GetWeatherData(Location location);

}

    public class WeatherData
    {
        public string temp { get; set; }
    }
    public class Location
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }

        public WeatherData main { get; set; }

    }
    public class WeatherDataServiceException
    {

    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           RunAsync().Wait();
        }
        static async Task RunAsync()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                string City = "ho chi minh";
                string Key = "ca618d97e8b322c883af330b7f103f2d";

                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("?q=" + City + "&APPID="+Key);
                if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {

                    Location w = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Location>().Result;

                    int res = Convert.ToInt32(w.main.temp);

                    //Console.WriteLine(w.main.temp.GetType());

                    Console.WriteLine("id city: " + w.id);
                    Console.WriteLine("city: " + w.name);
                     Console.WriteLine("temperature: " + w.main.temp);
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

However, it give me an error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

What do I need to change in order that the code will convert `string` to `int` correctly?

Comment: What is the content of `w.main.temp` before you convert?

Comment: Check the value of `w.main.temp`. Pretty good chances are that it is indeed in an incorrect format. Pay special attention to commas and decimal points.

Comment: when I write w.main.temp.GetType() it writes System.String

Comment: @user3488862 We know it's type, what is it's value.  `Console.WriteLine(w.main.temp);`

Comment: 304.15 but it's a string and I need to convert it to int because it is in Kelvin and I need it in degrees...

Comment: @user3488862 Why would you need it as an `int` to convert from Kelvin?  Just parst it as either a `double` or `decimal` or `float`.  Then if you really want an `int` you can then convert that to an `int`.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `int.TryParse(string, out int parameter)`

```
int res = 0;
bool parseSuccessful = int.TryParse(w.main.temp, out res);

//int.TryParse() returns a bool value to indicate whether parsing is Successful  or not.
```

If you want to parse a number left to `.`

e.g.

```
 w.main.temp = "123.45";
```

and you want output `int` to be `123`. Then use the following code

```
if (w.main.temp.IndexOf(".") >= 0)
{
    parseSuccessful = int.TryParse(w.main.temp.Substring(0, w.main.temp.IndexOf(".")), out res);
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use `int.TryParse` you should either capture the return value to know if it failed or put it in an `if` statement.  Also it can handle a `null` string (will return `false`).  Finally `int.TryParse` isn't going to work any better if the string isn't actually a valid integer value.

Comment: it returns false... how do it convert it successfully?

Comment: @user3488862 false means your string isn't a valid integer value.  It sounds like you've actually got a decimal value, so you either need to truncate the string starting with the decimal or first convert to a type that handles decimals then convert to `int`.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the response of the service you requested.

the w.main.temp has "." (Ex: 285.61, I guess it returns values as Kelvin) inside the value. So it is not integer.

You have several options based on what you want to have as a result.

1. you can get the left side of "."
2. You can first convert it to decimal and then get the floor or ceiling value of it then convert it to int.
3. etc...

Answer (score 0):

apparently you can't convert a string to an int if it not int number, it doesn't know how to cut it .
my number was 304.15 so you have to convert it to double.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your var is not an integer, you can either round it to an int first or just use a double instead of an int.